# What is "JavaGhost - Mass Twilio Checker"?

Tags: phishing, sms, fraud

Over the past week, the account credentials for my organization's Twilio account were stolen and used to send ~10,000 fraudulent SMS messages claiming to be from a major bank.

The passwords have all been changed, the secrets have been rotated, and the "subaccounts" created by the scammer have been removed.

I have no idea how they managed to get the information for this account, and I suspect I'll never know, since it only occurs in one config file on one server and the access logs for that server do not show any access to the file.

In analyzing the sent messages, I found a number of repetitions of the following text, all sent to the same phone number:

> JavaGhost - Mass Twilio Checker

I'm guessing that this is the attacker checking that they still have access to the account, but I've been looking around and can't seem to find any more information (other than that a number of people seem to use the nickname JavaGhost online).

I'm curious if anyone knows more about this type of attack and what is going on with these messages.

Comment: The same happened to me yesterday. Still trying to figure out how the api key got leaked

Comment: @Avram I wonder if yours and mine were at all similar. Mine is a [Laravel Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) application with the Twilio credentials stored in a `.env` file.

Comment: yes, Laravel 7.x app hosted on aws, Laravel was updated to the latest version of the 7.x branch about 2 weeks ago. Config is in .env file too

Comment: Mine is hosted on a physical server running cPanel, (and I am also the cPanel administrator) so I have full access to all the logs - SSH, web access, etc., and I cannot see anything in any of the logs that would have allowed the key to leak. Another administrator gets an email every time someone logs in via SSH, so we know that no one managed to get in as `root` (so they could not have modified the logs unless they also found a bug in cPanel itself).

Comment: I doubt it was stolen over SSH, it's more likely that the app is leaking config somewhere, at least in my case. My servers allow SSH login using private key only, and I am the only one who has access to it. The question is how to find out where it's leaking config? I've checked all the usual suspects, such as APP_DEBUG (it's disabled) or some API endpoints which return parts of the config (public data), but couldn't find anything which could leak secret data...